# How to navigate between scenes Cocos creator?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I'm working with cocos creator v 1.3.1

I want to know how to navigate between scenes,
Let say we have to scenes SceneA and SceneB.

First game load SceneA after that I can load second scene by calling this function `cc.director.loadScene('SceneB');`

After the I want to load SceneA, if I call like this `cc.director.loadScene('SceneA');`

It load new instance of SceneA but I want to load previous instance of SceneA.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what the scene stack is for.

```
cc.director.pushScene('SceneB');
```

will pause SceneA and start executing SceneB.

```
cc.director.popScene();
```

will exit from SceneB and unpause SceneA with its previous state intact.

Comment: Simulator: 102:Error: js_cocos2dx_Director_pushScene : Error processing arguments

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea you can persist the data (or state) you need in SceneA before you load SceneB, and when you come back to SceneA you can read the data (or state) persisted.  If you need switch between SceneA and SceneB frequently you may use  `cc.game.addPersistRootNode(this.xxx)`

Answer (score 1):

cc.director.loadScene(scene-name)  is the official way to exchange two scene